# Override custom extension adminhtml template in my module

Tags: magento2.3, layout, template

I want to over ride following tramplete:

```
app/code/Mageplaza/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/templates/order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml
```

Declared in :

```
app/code/Mageplaza/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/layout/mpeditorder_quick_edit.xml
```

with following:

```
<container name="content">
    <block class="Mageplaza\EditOrder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Edit\QuickEdit" name="mpeditorder.quick.edit" template="Mageplaza_EditOrder::order/edit/quick/form.phtml">
        <block class="Mageplaza\EditOrder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Edit\ShippingMethod" name="mpeditorder.shipping.method" template="Mageplaza_EditOrder::order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml" />
    </block>
</container>
```

I create my custom module depend on this extension having.
app/code/Evx/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/layout/mpeditorder_quick_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="mpeditorder.shipping.method">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Evx_EditOrder::order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Even Adding container on top is also not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="mpeditorder.shipping.method">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Evx_EditOrder::order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and copy template into :

```
app/code/Evx/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/templates/order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml
```

**Template not overriding.**

Answer (score 1):

Try to set template like below code,

> app/code/Evx/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/layout/mpeditorder_quick_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock class="Mageplaza\EditOrder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Edit\ShippingMethod" name="mpeditorder.shipping.method" template="Evx_EditOrder::order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml">
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Try this as well not working

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Then you should make sure the below things,

1. Check your "mpeditorder_quick_edit.xml" layout file is overridden by your theme.
2. Clean the cache

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect but You need to specify a load order in your component’s module.xml file using the `<sequence>` tag to ensure that needed files from other components are already loaded when your component loads.

`<sequence>` declares the list of components that must be loaded before the current component is loaded. It’s used for loading different kind of files: configuration files, view files (including CSS, Less, and template files), or setup classes. Note that  does not affect the loading of regular classes (non-setup classes). Setup classes are classes in the component that create or update database schema or data.

so,in **app/code/Evx/EditOrder/module.xml**

add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Evx_EditOrder" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Mageplaza_EditOrder" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: yes it is like that but not working

Comment: in config,php Evx_EditOrder is after Mageplaza_EditOrder?

Comment: Also your recommendation is not correct in sequence it should like.<module name="Mageplaza_EditOrder"/> not current module

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the template in your Layout File as below,

**app/code/Evx/EditOrder/view/adminhtml/layout/mpeditorder_quick_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="mpeditorder.shipping.method">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Evx_EditOrder::order/edit/shipping/method/list.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope It Will Work !!

Also Make Sure that This Template is not Somewhere Overriden in Theme Files.

Answer (score 0):

My posted code is perfectly fine for overriding the admin template. SO if any one want to override above is tested working example.
Actually issue which I was facing poorly written Mageplaza Extension. They are loading template from controller.